# python: create list from list returns less items

Tags: python, list, for-loop, double

I have a list of files, which I create with:

```
files=[f for f in os.listdir(source) if f.endswith('.tif')]
print(len(files))
264
```

This list contains 264 files, i.e.

```
 ...,'NL-HnWFA_2244_157.tif', 'NL-HnWFA_2244_158-001.tif', 'NL-HnWFA_2244_158-002.tif', 'NL-HnWFA_2244_159.tif', ...
```

From this list of files I want to substract the inventory (the "157" part) by doing:

```
inventories = []
for file in files:
  inventories.append(file.split('_')[2].split('-')[0].split('.')[0])
print(len(inventories))  
264
```

Then I have 264 items in the list
However, if I issue the command:

```
inventories = {fn.split('_')[2].split('-')[0].split('.')[0] for fn in files}
print(len(inventories))
263
```

The double values have been omitted and there are only 263 items.

Why are the double values been omitted in the second statement? 
Can I still (somehow) get the double values in the first statement?

Comment: In the second statement you are making a set object by enclosing the statement in {}. Use [] to get a list instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `set` (as you're doing `{...}`), always makes the sequence non-duplicate valued.

Nothing you can do about that.

So you gotta use the list comprehension one.

Demo:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,3]
>>> set(a)
{1, 2, 3}
>>> {i for i in a}
{1, 2, 3}
>>> {*a}
{1, 2, 3}
>>>
```

As in this [docs](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/):

> Sets are mutable unordered collections of unique elements. Common uses include membership testing, removing duplicates from a sequence, and computing standard math operations on sets such as intersection, union, difference, and symmetric difference.